# Pandas, pd.to_datetime(), convert date to datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I have a timeserie containing dates in format `dd/mm/yy` and datetime in format `dd/mm/yy hh:MM`.

I am using `pd.to_datetime` to convert them to proper datetime format, which works fine. However, I would like to convert the datapoints in format `dd/mm/yy` to `dd/mm/yy 00:00` or even better, `dd/mm/yy 08:00`.

How can I do that?

Comment: convert 'dd/mm/yy' string to 'dd/mm/yy 08:00' string?

Comment: Would be very helpful if you had a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + "  8:00"
```

Output:

```
'2017-01-27  8:00'
```